# Is it legal to use non-terminal twice in Backus-Naur grammar

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars

It's a school assignment:
The problem is:
Write a BN grammar for +67.

The given solution I have been given is following:

```
<digit>  ::= 6 | 7
<number> ::= <digit> | <digit> <number>
<+67>    ::= + <number>
```

My question is, when given this simple task, could it be derived like this?

```
<digit>  ::= 6 | 7
<number> ::= <digit> <digit> 
<+67>    ::= + <number>
```

More precisely, can I use same non-terminal twice in same rule?

Comment: Note the notion of [linear grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar).

Comment: To me the shortest answer is <+67> ::= +67  -  Was your assignment really stated as you write it above? A BN grammar is normally used to define a language, i.e., a set of string.  This set may contain only one element, but then you only need one rule.  And it is hardly useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to use the same non-terminal more than once in a rule.

Note that the two grammars you give do not express the same set of strings. 
The first grammar gives any sequence of 6 or 7 following the +, as  can be applied recursively. The second defines exactly four strings +66, +67. +76, +77.